# Using kotlin coroutines with room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In 2.1 Room added support for coroutines, but I can't get it working. It should be as easy as adding the dependency but somehow I'm overlooking something.

In my build.gradle I got the dependencies for coroutines, room and room-coroutines

```
dependencies { 
    def room_version = "2.2.0-beta01"
    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
    def coroutines_version = "1.1.1"
    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
}
```

I allready tryed resyncing gradle, cleaning and rebuilding the project.

In my Doa i have methods like the following

```
@Dao
interface PlanDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertVerPlan(verPlan: SqlVerPlan)
}
```

When trying to build the project Room doesn't know how to handle the suspending functions and the following error occurs:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
                                                        ^

error: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List<Long>.
    public abstract java.lang.Object insertVerPlan(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^
```

I seriously don't know what I'm missing and I can't find anyone with the same problem since the new Room version.

Comment: Hello, do not attach a link to git, I want to see how you work with coroutine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing different versions of the room library.

`android.arch.persistence.room:runtime` should be `androidx.room:room-runtime`

`android.arch.persistence.room:compiler` should be `androidx.room:room-compiler`

`android.arch.persistence.room:testing` should be `androidx.room:room-testing`

as per [Room#Declaring dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies)

Since you're using the old coordinates for the compiler it does not know about the `suspend` support.